# Sum of Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, arithmetic-expressions

In my dataframe I have a column that is timestamp formatted as 2021-11-18 00:58:22.705
I wish to create a column that displays the time elapsed from each row to the interval time (first time).
There are 2 ways in which I can think of doing this but I don't seem to know how to make it happen.

Method 1:
To subtract each time stamp to the row above.

```
df["difference"]= df["timestamp"].diff()
```

Now that this time difference has been calculated I would like to create another column that sums each time difference but it keeps the sum from the delta above (elapsed time from start of process)

Method 2:
I guess another way would be to calculate the timestamp of each row to the interval time stamp (first one)
I do not know how I would do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting a `variable` that stores your time from the "first time" and then take the time elapsed from each row and either add or subtract it from your firs time `variable`.

Comment: You will have a hard time finding help without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think you are looking for `df["difference"].cumsum()`

Answer (score 0):

not completely understood the type of difference needed so adding both which I think are reasonable:

```
import pandas as pd

times = pd.date_range('2022-05-23', periods=20, freq='0D30min')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': times})

df['difference_in_min'] = (df.Timestamp - df.Timestamp.min()).astype('timedelta64[m]')
df['cumulative_dif_in_min'] = df.difference_in_min.cumsum()

print(df)

             Timestamp  difference_in_min  cumulative_dif_in_min
0  2022-05-23 00:00:00                0.0                    0.0
1  2022-05-23 00:30:00               30.0                   30.0
2  2022-05-23 01:00:00               60.0                   90.0
3  2022-05-23 01:30:00               90.0                  180.0
4  2022-05-23 02:00:00              120.0                  300.0
5  2022-05-23 02:30:00              150.0                  450.0
6  2022-05-23 03:00:00              180.0                  630.0
7  2022-05-23 03:30:00              210.0                  840.0
8  2022-05-23 04:00:00              240.0                 1080.0
```